# Is it worth to use if-else statement as Java optional pattern?

Tags: java, optional

I came to a point while refactoring using `if {} else {}` code with Java optionals. While optimizing code it turned to a result to this:

> ```
> Optional.of(myBoolean).filter(b -> b).ifPresent(b -> {/*my code if true*/});
> ```

I recognized `filter(b -> b)` is not the way i wanted to use optionals thus i turned it to

> ```
> If.is(myBoolean).then(b -> {/*my code if true*/}).orElse(b -> {/*my code if false*/});
> ```

The code for the `If` class I wrote to handle this is:

```
public class If {

    private boolean isTrue;

    public If(final boolean value) {
        isTrue = value;
    }

    public If then(final Consumer s) {
        if (isTrue) {
            s.accept(null);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void orElse(final Consumer s) {
        if (!isTrue) {
            s.accept(null);
        }
    }

    public static If is(final boolean value) {
        return new If(value);
    }
}
```

Is this a good (whatever good is or should be) approach using the `if {} else {}` statement in Java?

Comment: Hi Daniel, is it possible to share the code you have refactored with us? Often `if-else` branches can be replaced by polymorphism.

Comment: What does this class have to do with Optionals? Which advantage does it have over a regular `if`/`else`?

Comment: I don't quite understand the need of `.filter(b -> b)` in the first code example, it would be the exact same thing without that part, right?

Comment: Hi @SimonForsberg, I checked again the `filter` method `Optional.of(true).ifPresent(b -> System.out.println("1: " + b));`
`Optional.of(false).ifPresent(b -> System.out.println("2: " + b));`
`Optional.of(true).filter(b -> b).ifPresent(x -> System.out.println("3: " + x));`
`Optional.of(false).filter(b -> b).ifPresent(x -> System.out.println("4: " + x));`

The console output was
`1: true`
`2: false`
`3: true`

and `2: false` should not appear (as `4: false` doesn't). Therefore `filter(b -> b)` is necessary. That led me to the `If` class.

Comment: @DanielGschösser Oh right, you want to turn all those `false` booleans to an empty optional, I get it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My first instinct is that your code is a pretty “cool” way to rewrite if else statements, but I don’t think it gains you too much. If you have massive amounts of if trees and want to make them more readable, I would consider using polymorphism to your advantage or, when appropriate, strategy pattern.

If you want some help refactoring a certain if tree please feel free to post the code and we can help.

There are often, IMO, two big reasons to make a new abstraction.

1) to decrease the mental load on the maintainers of this code or

2) to increase the ability to add new features in the future.

Both of these are, of course, related. My question is, and feel free to comment below, does your if abstraction decrease maintainer mental load through simplicity or brevity and/or does your if abstraction improve the ability to add new features in the future? If not then you need to consider why you are doing it in the first place.

Comment: Well i guess the only advantage is to write code in one line readable from left to right. That was more or less the intention for this (escalated) codereview that lead to the question here.

Comment: @DanielGschösser `If.is(myBoolean).then(b -> {/*my code if true*/}).orElse(b -> {/*my code if false*/});` can also be written as `if (myBoolean) { /* my code if true */ } else { /* my code if false */ }` which can also be written in one line readable from left to right. Just because it can be written in more lines doesn't mean that it has to.

Answer (score 9):

**There is nothing inherently wrong with if-else statements.**

Please do not use Optionals as replacement for if-else statements. They were not intended for that purpose. Optional was intended to convey the *possibility of null-values in public interfaces* in code, instead of just documentation, and only that. Even using optional in a private method is against it's intention (you're supposed to know what your own code does).

Please read this answer from one of the architects behind the Optional class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327957/should-java-8-getters-return-optional-type/26328555#26328555

**Exercise**: Calculate the number of object creations and method calls involved in a Optional-if-else compared to a regular if-else and evaluate what effect the difference, if there is one, has on the optimizations.

**Implementation**

The If-class is intended to replace if-else-statements, but it does not follow the same logic as it allows multiple then-statements. It also lacks support for else-if constructs. Regular if-else statements do not consume anything so the parameter type of `then` and `orElse` should be `Runnable` (the fact that you pass a `null` to the consumer is a tell tale about code smell).